# Possible to create small business network from Homegroup setup?

Tags: user-accounts, homegroup, small-business-server

I have a network of 12 Win7 Professional and 1 Win10 Pro computers, a Sonicwall TZ-100, 2 unmanaged switched, a Linux-based POS server with no admin capabilities, and a network shared USB hard drive.

I'd like to start managing users, groups, permissions, and tasks from a single PC instead of running around the building.

Currently, there is no SBS in place, and everything is joined in a Homegroup, for sharing capabilities. This is obviously not the ideal small business setup.

Is there a way, without purchasing a SBS, to start creating and managing users across this network? I have successfully created service users for things like backups and task scheduling, but I have to manually add the permissions on the target PC for these things to work, and it's so convoluted and not standardized that I want to vomit.

Comment: These functions can be handled by a Linux server acting as a domain controller, almost all functions of a Microsoft SBS can be duplicated via a Linux computer running just about any major distribution. A quick Google search for 'linux domain controller' will yield all sorts of results to get you started. Depending on where you live, you maybe able to find a local vendor to help set this up as it is becoming more common to see this type of setup (but it still isn't "common" by any means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that if you mean Microsoft Small Business Server (SBS) or just any server that you can use in a small business environment.

To centrally manage user accounts (specifically Windows accounts) you want to have a domain. For you to have a domain, you need a server running a Windows Server Operating System (e.g. Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012). This server will need to be setup as a domain controller. This role means that it will run active directory services which is what maintains the central user database for your domain. Each computer is then joined to your domain (this is only possible with professional, enterprise, and ultimate Windows Operating System versions). That way each user has a single username that can be used to access any of the computers joined to the domain.

If you mean Windows Small Business Server when you use the term SBS, please understand that is a Microsoft solution that includes Active Directory and Exchange (mail server) in a single server. If you need a mail server, then a Windows SBS server may be a good solution (of course with Office365 the you might prefer to have Microsoft host the exchange server instead of you maintaining exchange too).

If you just need to be able to manage local user accounts (the accounts are stored on each computer not on  server) then you can use Microsoft Management Console to manage local user accounts on multiple computers so you don't need to physically go to each computer to manage users, groups, and permissions.

To use Microsoft Management Console, please perform the following steps:

- Click **Start**
- Type **MMC**
- Click **mmc.exe**

Now you need to choose what aspects of your computers you want to manage. Click **File**, and **Add/Remove Snap-in**. To manage local user accounts and groups, click **Local Users and Groups**, then click **Add**. When you click Add you will be asked if you want to load Local Users and Groups for the computer you are on or a different computer on the network. To add Local Users and Groups on a different computer, select **Another computer** and type the name of the computer in the blank to the right. If the name of the computer is test you would type \test in the blank to the right and then click **Finish**. Then you can click **OK** and you will see Local Users and Groups with the name of the computer it is controlling in parenthesis. You can do the same thing with managing shares by adding the **Shared Folders** snap-in and Tasks by adding the **Task Scheduler** snap-in.

Mind you that doing what I described in MMC will allow you to change things on computers without having to go to each one, but what you really want is a Windows domain controller and to join the workstations to the domain so you can centrally manage users, groups, permissions, file storage, and printers. You will need to install Active Directory services, File Server, and Print Server roles on the Windows server you install as your domain controller.

Comment: I was specifically referring to Microsoft Small Business Server, however I don't have any SBS at all.

Comment: So your answer is you can either use MMC as I explained to manage accounts, shares, and tasks from one computer or you need to get a Windows server that you setup as a domain controller (BETTER). The question for you is do you need a Exchange server or not. If you do then go with SBS if you don't then you can go with Server 2012. If you have never installed a Windows server OS or configured a server to be a domain controller, you might want to download the trial Windows Server 2012 from Technet. The page is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the answer. I do not need exchange, as our email setup is only the two owners and myself. I'm going to give MMC a try before I go looking for a server. It may be all I need. Our POS software has its own management service, and the only other things I need to manage are backups, printers, staging and installing programs (not too important) and controlling scheduling. We shall see shortly!

Comment: No problem! Please feel free to upvote my answer and/or mark the answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I've got it working, and this is perfect! was able to uninstall Mcafee, use Mcafee removal tool, and install Kapersky, then change all the backup settings with virtually no effort. 6 hours saved. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad that worked for you! If you can convince your management to buy a Windows server so you can create a domain and join the workstations to the domain it will make your life much easier. :)